# How to include version number in filename of a fetched lib?

Tags: ant, ivy

Using Ivy with this Ant target:

```
<target name="retrieve-jars">
   <ivy:retrieve pattern="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/[artifact].[ext]" />
</target>
```

to fetch dependencies such as this (off of default Maven repos):

```
<dependency org="com.google.code.gson" name="gson" rev="2.0"/>
```

...the resulting filename is e.g. "**gson.jar**".

While it might be a dubious practice to do so, I'm interested in knowing if you can include the version number in the filename, making it e.g. "**gson-2.0.jar**".

I tried `[version]` and `[ver]` but those do not work; I end up with e.g. "gson-[version].jar".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **`[revision]`**:

```
[artifact]-[revision].[ext]
```

http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.0.0/ant.html